# How can I automate creating a folder, subfolders, and an empty file inside?

Tags: bash, scripts, directory

Almost every day, I have to repeat multiple times these three steps:

1. Create a folder - Ex.: `Alpha`
2. Create sub folders - Ex.: `Alpha_A`, `Alpha_B`, `Alpha_C`
3. In the sub folder `Alpha_A` create a new empty document - Ex.: `Text.txt`

Is there a way to automate these three steps?

---

I created this script following a tutorial:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Name of new folder: \c"
read folder
echo "the new folder name is: $folder"
mkdir /home/john/Desktop/test/ $folder
cd /home/john//Desktop/test/$folder
mkdir sub_1
mkdir sub_2
mkdir sub_3
```

But I get two error messages:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/john/Desktop/test/’: File exists
```

```
./script_2.sh: line 7: cd: /home/john/Desktop/test/new: No such file or directory
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir Alpha
cd Alpha
mkdir Alpha_A Alpha_B Alpha_C
cd Alpha_A
touch Text.txt
```

Comment: this are a lot of steps, you can do it all in 2 steps

Comment: Is there a way to specify the name of the main folder? For example, instead of Alpha, is there a way for the algorithm to ask the name of the folder and then execute the remaining commands? Something like this: 1.Ask name of new folder; 2.create main folders; 3.create a txt file in a specific folder. So the algorithm would be something like this: Ask name of new folder->John; 2.create 3 sub-folders->pdf_files, doc_files, images; 3.create a text file named TEXT in the sub-folder IMAGE.

Comment: Google "`read` in bash".

Comment: #!/bin/bash

echo -e "Name of new folder: \c"
read folder
echo "the new folder name is: $folder"
mkdir /Desktop/test/ $folder
mkdir /Desktop/test/$folder/sub_1
mkdir /Desktop/test/$folder/sub_2
mkdir /Desktop/test/$folder/sub_3

it says: so such file or directory but then the directory is created but not the sub-folders

Comment: this is unreadable, you must edit your question to add this.

Comment: I edited the original post as i cannot seem to find a way to properly format the comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110722/discussion-between-kashish-and-simple-mind).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p Alpha/Alpha_{A,B,C}
touch Alpha/Alpha_A/Test.txt
```

Only 2 lines, and does not change the current directory.

Read `man mkdir bash`.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a bash file and use mkdir and other commands to create the file.

Or if you want a more advanced approach, I would recommend using Python, which is great for automating tasks and you may even be able to do more advanced jobs such as putting text in the file or other things.